# Doing two average populations for countries in one SQL query

Tags: sql, average

I have a table of `cities` with the following information:

```
name, country, population, capital, shape
```

I need to get the average of the populations for each city, in two specific countries (Argentina  and Mexico), without adding them together.

Is there a way to do both average queries in one?

I am just wondering if this can or can't be done.

Comment: What do you mean with "average of the populations for each city"? Do you have many rows in the table for each city?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use something like this where you `GROUP BY` the city and country:

```
select city, country, avg(population) AvgPop
from yourtable
where country in ('Argentina', 'Mexico')
group by city, country
```

Comment: @KyleCharneski . . . You should accept this answer if it worked for you.